# How should I do if the pattern in awk cmd is a bash variable and contains special character?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

**Description:** The 1-line awk cmd is used to print all lines after the matched line in my shell script as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
awk "f;/${PATTERN}/{f=1}" ${FILE}
```

Since the ${PATTERN} may contains special character, the cmd will fail in this case.

**Q1.** How should I handle such kind of situation if regex is used in awk?

**Q2.** Is it possible to just use the raw string in this cmd instead of regex e.g. ***/$PATTERN/***  to avoid the special character problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close.  It's better to pass shell variables in to awk with `-v` than to place them in the awk script directly.

```
awk -v pat="${PATTERN}" 'f; $0 ~ pat {f=1}' "${FILE}"
```

If `${PATTERN}` is not a regex, you can use a different operator:

```
awk -v pat="${PATTERN}" 'f; $0 == pat {f=1}' "${FILE}"
```

or you can even handle non-regex substrings:

```
awk -v pat="${PATTERN}" 'f; index($0, pat) {f=1}' "${FILE}"
```